# Can we install SQL Server standard edition using clickonce deployment of Visual Studio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, clickonce

I'm trying to find ways while publishing application from Visual Studio 2015 to install SQL Server other than SQL Server Express edition if possible.

Comment: You cannot do this, because the non-Express editions of SQL Server all require valid licenses to use, and you're not allowed to package a product that you're not licensing in your own installer. You will need to ensure that your end users have the valid SQL Server licenses, and they need to install SQL Server separately

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deploying a database and application with ClickOnce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195733/deploying-a-database-and-application-with-clickonce)

Comment: ...or live with SQL LocalDb, or Sql Server Express / Compact Edition.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. But if you need exactly SQL Express raw installation then you can to try this workaround:

1. You need to code application something like "net.Launcher", because ClickOnce application entry point (Launch .exe application) must be only .NET application. After client got it published, downloaded and executed - net.launcher.exe beginning download from some your local resource or server SQL Server installation package and saves it somewhere locally.
2. After download process down it's starts "sql express silent install" process and closing after finish. Don't forget to check installation status!

P.S. I didn't have seen any limitations about file size for manifest, so you can add package as zip archive or something like that as Binary content to you application (FCL have possibility uncompress it to temporary folder).